# Apply delay on ng-blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` to show/hide a button. on `focus` of an input, a button is shown and on `blur` it is hidden. Show/hide is being performed using `ng-show`. On click of this button a function gets called.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aditya_Ponkshe/m8ab96su/)**

Issue is that `ng-blur` us being called first and the button is getting hidden before the click event is fired, hence function which is to be called from that button is never getting called.

I have already fixed it by using `setTimeout()` but later found that it is not really a good solution. Is there any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: What about this http://jsfiddle.net/m8ab96su/3/

Comment: What about removing the button completely and add the logic on the blur event.

Comment: @dfsq as i said, i can;t really remove ng-blur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseleave`
change your button to

```
        <button ng-click="click()" ng-show="show||mouseover" ng-mouseover="mouseover=true" ng-mouseleave="mouseover=false">Click to change</button>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xr9dk2pc/2/)

Comment: ohhh i am sorry it is fixed

Comment: cool, that works! but can you please explain what you did there?

Comment: i'm sorry for delay. i use ng-mouseover and ng-mouseleave for determine when mouse is over the button. . . sorry again my english is so bad!!!

Comment: Tricky ! nice solution

Answer (score 1):

why don't you change the `$scope.show=false;` in the click event of the button.

In other words, remove the blur event, and the click event will be like this.

```
 $scope.click = function(){
    alert("fuu")
    $scope.text = "We changed it";
    $scope.show=false;    
}
```

Comment: are you suggesting that I should remove ng-blur itself?

Comment: I can't remove ng-blur . I want that button to be hidden on blur of input.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a *bool* can help you to determine the state if it's needed to hide or show the button. On mouseover of the button change the *bool* to determine the execution of blur function.

*Try this ways :*

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <div>{{ text }}</div>
    <input ng-focus="focus()" ng-blur="blur()"></input>
    <button ng-click="click()" ng-show="show==true" ng-mouseover="mouseover()">Click to change</button>
</div>
```

**angularjs :**

```
function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.show=false;
    $scope.blurAll = true;
    $scope.text = "this thing will change on click";

    $scope.focus = function(){
        console.log("buu");
        $scope.show=true;
    }
    $scope.blur = function(){
        if(blurAll){
            console.log("baaa");
            $scope.show=false;
        }
    }

    $scope.click = function(){
            alert("fuu");
            $scope.text = "We changed it";
            $scope.show = false;

    }

    $scope.mouseover = function(){
        blurAll = false;
    };
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/s0wv8y6f/)

Answer (score 0):

use a custom directive which introduce a delay

```
app.directive('ngBlurDelay',['$timeout',function($timeout){
return {
    scope:{
        ngBlurDelay:'&'
    },
    link:function(scope, element, attr){
    element.bind('blur',function(){
       $timeout(scope.ngBlurDelay,200);
    });
    }
};
}])
```